# Is there a way to save memory when I add many children on canvas in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

```
void MainWindow_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   Ellipse el = new Ellipse();

   el.Fill = ellipse.Fill;
   el.Width = ellipse.Width;
   el.Height = ellipse.Height;

   Point p = e.GetPosition(this.canvasPrint);
   Canvas.SetLeft(el, p.X);
   Canvas.SetTop(el, p.Y);
   canvasPrint.Children.Add(el);
}
```

This is the sample code of the program that I made. I am adding ellipses on a canvas. The point of each ellipse is the point of the mouse cursor. When the mouse is moving, a new ellipse is generated and added so it works like a brush tool in MS Paint.

However, it consumes too much memory. So after a while, the program becomes slower. Is there any way to solve this problem? Can't I reuse the same ellipse object when I add it on the canvas?

Comment: Don't "paint" with controls. The controls be removed until they are they are, well no longer needed. If the same ellipse object is re-used it will simply be *moved* to the new location.

Comment: Thanks! Then what should I use when I do 'painting'? I searched about InkCanvas... Is it a right approach??

Comment: If the goal is just to "highlight/trace" simply create less objects; instead of adding a million ellipses add a fat path stroke whenever there is a significant angle/time-change in the mouse. This should slow down the rate of elements added so that any slowdown (which there will *eventually* be) is inconsequential/unnoticeable.

Comment: add only one ellipse in the window constructor, keep a reference to it and just move it in the mouse handler.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `DrawingVisual` and `DrawingContext` to draw your brush path. `DrawingContext` is similar to Windows Forms `Graphics` object. So in your situation, just draw your brush path on the same `DrawingContext`.

Comment: This. DrawingVisual is very light and designed for this sort of thing.